# Can't build 2 tables JOIN with only certain fields to select in Nhb 4

Tags: nhibernate

I try to run query like this with Nhibernate v.4:

```
Select o.Number, c.Address
From Order o join Client c on o.ClientId = c.Id
Where c.Name = "John"
```

Tried many ways to do that with JoinQueryOver and JoinAlias but nothing helps, endup with error "could not resolve property: Address of Order"

```
Session.QueryOver<Order>()
                    .JoinQueryOver(s => s.Client)
                    .Where(() => c.Name == "John")
                .SelectList(x => .Select(Projections.Property<Order>(o => o.Number)
                .SelectList(x => .Select(Projections.Property<Order>(o => o.Client.Address))
```

or like this

```
...
.SelectList(x => .Select(Projections.Property<Order>(o => o.Number)
.SelectList(x => .Select(Projections.Property<Client>(c => c.Address))
```

What is the right way to build the query or something very similar? Problem with 'Select' operator, 'Where' part works fine. I can also build non-join queries by this 2 entities separate from each other and it works well, but no idea how to join them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've figured out how to make it work:

```
Client client = null;
OrderClientDto dto = null;

var result = Session.QueryOver<Order>()
                    .JoinAlias(o => o.Client, () => client)
                    .Where(() => c.Name == "John")
                    .SelectList(x => x
                        .Select(o => o.Number).WithAlias(() => dto.Number)
                        .Select(() => o.Client.Address).WithAlias(() => dto.Address))
.TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<OrderClientDto>())
                        .List<OrderClientDto>();
```

Nhb is far from being intuitive and convenient. Same query is much easier to write in EF.